# Is there a faster way to concat huge data frames (40GB) using pandas

Tags: pandas, performance, memory, concatenation

I have 3 huge data frames of 40 GB size, I opened them using chunks. Then, I wanna concatenate them together. Here is what I tried:

```
    path = 'path/to/myfiles'
    files = [os.path.join(path,i) for i in os.listdir(path) if i.endswith('tsv')]
    for file in files:
        cols = ['col1','col2','col3']
        chunks = pd.read_table(file, sep='\t', names=cols, chunksize=10000000)
```

However, when I try to concatenate all the files, it is taking forever.
I would like to have some suggestions to concatenate all the data frames quicker/faster.

Comment: have you looked into [dask](https://dask.org/) ? I've not had a chance to use it myself but I've heard great things about this project and data that's too big to fit into memory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have never looked into this, will take a look.

Comment: But will you actually ever need to keep the entire dataframes in memory for your use-case? There are alternative file formats (HDFS, PARQUET etc.), and there are alternative commands to `concat`. It helps if you tell us if you mainly need columnar access, or row access, and sequential or random access. (e.g. Can you just serial process each (concat'ed) row, or doing arbitrary filter across multiple columns, or what?)

Comment: Also you say the runtime is slow, but you may be blowing out memory instead. Be aware the `pd.read_table(..., chunksize=1e7)` parameter is not the size of the memory chunk; it's the number of rows in the chunk. The actual memory used for the chunk depends on size of a row in each dataframe, so if one combined row occupied 10Kb, then attempting to use `chunksize=1e7` of those would take 100Gb, which is huge. Try lower chunksizes. Also you should never hardwire constants like that into your source, esp. if they would cause your job to fail on most medium-sized machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.tsv` and `.csv` are fairly slow formats to read/write. I've found parquet works best for most of the stuff I end up doing. It's quite fast on reads and writes, and also allows you to read back a chunked folder of files as a single table easily. It does require string column names, however:

```
In [102]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100000, 100)), columns=[str(i) for i in range(100)])

In [103]: %time df.to_parquet("out.parquet")
Wall time: 980 ms

In [104]: %time df.to_csv("out.csv")
Wall time: 14 s

In [105]: %time df = pd.read_parquet("out.parquet")
Wall time: 195 ms

In [106]: %time df = pd.read_csv("out.csv")
Wall time: 1.53 s
```

If you don't have control over the format those chunked files are in, you'll obviously need to pay the read cost of them at least once, but converting them could still save you some time in the long run if you do a lot of other read/writes.

Answer (score 2):

1. CSV/TSV is a very slow file format, not optimized.
2. **You probably don't need to keep the entire dataset in-memory. Your use-case probably doesn't need full random column- and row-access across the entire combined (120GB) dataset**.

- (Can you process each row/chunk/group (e.g. zipcode, user_id, etc.) serially? e.g. to compute aggregates, summary statistics, features? Or do you need to be able to apply arbitrary filters across columns (which columns), or rows (which columns)? e.g. *"Get all userid's who used service X within the last N days"*. You can choose a higher-performance file format based on your use-case. There are alternative file formats (HDFS, PARQUET etc.) Some are optimized for columnar access, or row access, some for sequential or random access. There is also PySpark.
- **You don't necessarily need to combine your dataset into one huge monolithic 120GB file.**

1. You're saying the runtime is slow, but likely you're blowing out memory (in which case runtime goes out the window), so your first check your memory usage.

- Your code is trying to **read in and store all chunks of each file, not process them individual chunk-by-chunk across the three files**: `for file in files: ... chunks = pd.read_table(file, ... chunksize=10000000)`. See [Iterating through files chunk by chunk, in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-chunking).
- after you fix that, `chunksize=1e7` parameter is **not the size of the memory chunk**; it's only the number of rows in the chunk. That value is insanely large. If one row of the combined dataframes were to take say 10Kb, then a chunk of 1e7 such rows would take 100Gb(!), which will not fit in most machines.

1. If you must stick with using CSV, **process one single chunk across each of the three files, then write its output to file, don't leave all the chunks hanging around in-memory.** Also reduce your chunksize (try e.g. 1e5 or less, and measure the memory and runtime improvement). Also don't hardcode it, figure out a sane value per-machine, and/or make it a command-line parameter. Monitor your memory usage.